# Runnig Yesod Compiled Project on FpComplete using Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, yesod, fpcomplete

Hi sorry about this issue, i'm run out of ideas of how to access my deployed project on our main domain server.

By following the [Guidelines](https://github.com/snoyberg/keter/#quick-start) provided in the GitHub I installed properly the keter, put the `.keter` file in the `/opt/keter/incoming` path but once i access it on the browser it always see the nginx page.

Also I use fpcomplete IDE for my project and I just download the file executable file there.

Thank in advance

Answer (score -2):

I've solve this by following the instruction given to me on [Github](https://github.com/snoyberg/keter/issues/78)